# Ec2 Instance Login issue - Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, packer

I have created an instance using my AMI (from a golden AMI - this has default 5 volumes mounted in it - as per the cis recommendation I think). When I spin up instance with this AMI I don't see any issue with the login but there are no drives mounted. So I have defined in my packer code to have those volumes attached under launch_block_device_mappings and ami_block_device_mappings. Now I can see my own AMI has the drives attached.

Here the problem comes: when I spin up with out mounting those drives my instance allows me to login however when I run below its not allowing me to login :

```
Error : Access Denied.
```

Packer Code under provisioners : (just created a new directory called scripts and executing it - earlier tried executing from packer got error so tried copying into instance and executing from there).

```
    {
         "type": "shell",
         "inline": [
            "sudo chmod u+x /scripts/mountpartitions.sh",
            "sudo sh /scripts/mountpartitions.sh",
            "sudo rm -rf /scripts"
         ],
        "execute_command": "{{ .Vars }} sudo -E -S sh '{{ .Path }}'"
    }
```

Mountshell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdj
echo '/dev/xvdj /tmp ext4 defaults 1 2' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/xvdj /tmp

sudo mkdir -p /srv/home
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /srv/home
sudo rsync -av /home/* /srv/home/
sudo rm -rf /home/*
sudo umount /srv/home
echo '/dev/xvdf /home ext4 defaults 1 2' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /home
sudo rm -rf /srv/home/

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdh
echo '/dev/xvdh /var/log ext4 defaults 1 2' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/xvdh /var/log

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdi
sudo mkdir /var/log/audit
echo '/dev/xvdi /var/log/audit ext4 defaults 1 2' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mount /dev/xvdi /var/log/audit

sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk /dev/xvdl
  o # clear the in memory partition table
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  1 # partition number 1
    # default - start at beginning of disk
    # default, extend partition to end of disk
  t # change a partition's system id
 82 # 82  Linux swap
  p # print the in-memory partition table
  w # write the partition table
  q # and we're done
EOF
echo '/dev/xvdl1 none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
mkswap -L /dev/xvdl1 /dev/xvdl1
swapon -a
```

I've tried building instance with AMI manually and logged in with pem key to see if where is the error, I can see all the sudoers are available.

Also tried the script like below from user data rather from packer code ( from the ami where no drives are attached) but still same.

Verified secure, message logs it just shows in

```
Jul  9 01:39:38 sshd[10595]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
Jul  9 01:39:49 sshd[10595]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure;
```

Instance should allow me to login via AD authentication.

Why I'm getting error just by adding a script for mounting drives?

Answer (score 0):

Found that we were missing restart of sssd as we were only doing ssshd which resolved it.